# Adding labels on form through loop

Tags: powershell

i m trying to draw windows logo on form through powershell. following code will put only one dot on form. whats wrong with it?

```
 $labels = @(0)*5
   for ($i=0;$i -lt 4;$i++)
     { $labels[$i] = new-object system.window.forms.label
$labels[$i].location = new-object system.drawing.point($i+10,5)
  $labels[$i].text = $i.tostring()
$main_form.controls.add($labels[$i])
}
}
   $main_form.showdialog()
```

the ouput is just one dot on form. changing text value to say "a" prints only one a.

Comment: Do you see a difference if you move them a little further apart than 1 pixel? `New-Object System.Drawing.Point(((20*$i)+10),5)`

Comment: sir tried a number of variants in location statement but in vain. is there any thing wrong with code other than location issue?

Comment: Hard to tell, the code you've posted is neither valid nor complete :) Can you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your x and y coordinates the wrong way round - `Controls.Add` takes `x` then `y`, but you're putting all your controls on the same `y` coordinate, and your x offset for each control is 1 pixel (you might have meant `$i * 10` instead of `$i + 10`) so they're all overlapping each other.

There's also a bunch of typos - e.g. `system.window.forms` - `window` instead of `windows`, and `new-object system.drawing.point($i+10,5)` doesn't even work (it gives a `Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.` error). It's worth spending a bit of time testing the code you post before submitting it, even to the point of cutting and pasting it from your question to make sure it actually runs because you're more likely to get a response from someone!

In any case, the following works for me:

```bsh
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Windows.Forms";
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Drawing";

$main_form = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Form;

$labels = @();
for( $i=0; $i -lt 5; $i++ )
{

    $label = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label;

    $label.BackColor = "Orange";
    $label.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Point(10, ($i * 25));
    $label.Text = $i.ToString();

    $labels += $label;
    $main_form.Controls.Add($label);

}

$main_form.ShowDialog();
```

which shows a form like this:

[image]

Feel free to adapt this to your needs.

Comment: firstly. thanks for putting me right. yes that was real bad on my part but its complicated ;)...secondly. your code works fine as far as label gen is concerned. but i need to draw dots on form to ultimately generate windows logo. can u pl just let me know how to draw a  10mm dotted line with the help of this code?